# Angular Mat-menu to be open state by default on page load

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-storybook

I'm trying to have mat-menu to be open by default on page load but not programmatically. Currently on click event the mat-menu opens up. But I need the mat-menu to opened up on page load.

I need something like this - https://gitlab-org.gitlab.io/gitlab-ui/?path=/story/base-dropdown--secondary